# printf() statement makes a difference to my return value? - C Programming

Tags: c

I'm experimenting with one of the functions in the K&R C Programming Language book and using pointers to write the strindex function rather than array notation. I have a strange problem that if I include a printf() statement at either of the two points in my code below then the function returns the correct index (6 in this case), but if I leave the printf() statements out then the function returns -1.

I really can't see why this should make any difference at all and would be grateful for any clarification. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int strindex(char *a, char *b) {

    char *pa;
    char *astart = a;
    char *pb = b;
    int len;

    while(*pb++ != '\0')
        len++;

    while(*a != '\0') {
        pa = a;
        pb = b;
        for(;*pb != '\0' && *pa == *pb; pa++, pb++)
            ;
        if(len > 0 && *pb == '\0') {
            return a - astart;
        }
        //printf("%c\n", *a);
        a++;
    }
    //printf("%c\n", *a);
    return -1;
}

int main() {

    char *a = "experiment";
    char *b = "me";

    printf("index is %d\n", strindex(a, b));

    return 0;
}
```

Many thanks

Joe

Comment: I don't get any change in behaviour (other than printing out the characters)...

Comment: I pasted what you just posted and I get "index is 6" as the output. I think you had some other issue (like perhaps not recompiling?)

Comment: Don't see any obvious bugs...

Comment: Your code looks like it should work correctly, and indeed behaves correctly (prints "index is 6") when compiled with gcc (v4.3.4) here regardless of optimisation level. What compiler and settings are you using?

Comment: The behavior of the code changes when you add instructions to view the values... looks like a *Quantum entanglement* disruption problem to me...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is the automatic variable `len`. Since you don't initialize it, it starts with a indeterminate (garbage) value. Then you increment it, so it will end up as 'garbage + length of b'. Any single change to the compiled code, like an extra `printf` call can change the starting value of `len` and thus change the behaviour of your program.

The solution: `int len = 0;`, and see if you can get more warnings from your compiler. If you are using `gcc`, use the `-O -Wall -Wextra` flags. Then you should get a warning like:

> strindex.c:8: warning: ‘len’ may be used uninitialized in this function

Comment: Ha. Brilliant. Thanks very much Schot. It's working now and I understand the explanation. Given that len was garbage I'm suprised it worked at all.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I was using -Wall only. Using -O gives the 'may be used uninitialized' warning. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Joe: Yes, it is counterintuitive you need to enable optimisation to get certain warnings. Other useful flags are `-ansi` or `-std=c99` in combination with `-pedantic`.